# Mach Zehnder phase change?

Tags: modulation, optoelectronics, phase

According to [Comsol](https://www.comsol.com/model/mach-zehnder-modulator-15061), a multiphisics simulation software company, a mach zehnder modulator "modulates" the input signal by splitting it into two parallel branches, affecting the relative phase on one or both of the parallel branches, and recombining each branch at the output. The relative phase change is imposed by an electrically controlled index of refraction.

My question:

Is the "phase" mentioned here only applicable to a single sinusoid? If two superimposed sinusoids were input into this system, would they each experience an equal phase shift  or an equal time shift?

Comment: A change to the index of refraction would impose a fixed time delay, not a fixed phase delay. But I know nothing of mach zehnder modulators. You may want to search using the term "Hilbert transform" to read about a fixed phase shift (over a wide frequency range).

Answer (score 1):

Warning: This answer is based primarily on university courses on optical networks. There could be a bit of real-life missing.

So in traditional single-wavelength systems, we have usually considered the assumption that \$V_{\pi}\$, the half-wavelength voltage, is constant for each optical band, but that the value between the bands will usually be different, to be good enough. In traditional systems, the 1550 nm band is quite popular, so quite often, there's not much need to run multi-band systems.

In reality, the \$V_{\pi}\$ is wavelength-dependent even within the same band, but the differences are usually small. So what happens in real-life is that you'll set the voltage to some value and that value will cause different phase-shift for each wavelength going through the modulator. This will give you a limit on the usable bandwidth of the signal going through the modulator. For example, [Analysis and Improvement of Mach–Zehnder
Modulator Linearity Performance for Chirped
and Tunable Optical Carriers](http://www.photonics.ucla.edu/media/publication/journal/101109JLT20021007945.pdf) paper gives some bandwidth values for different types of MZMs. In any case, the bandwidths are in the terahertz range, so for "normal" applications, this is not a big issue, but for very wide DWDM, this could be problematic.

In the end, it's the duty of the engineer designing the system to determine what's good enough and what could be problematic.

Answer (score 0):

This is an optical laser system with coherent light and beam splitter that uses a reference plane with a voltage controlled dielectric at optical wavelengths so that relative diffraction can be used for various experiments in Physics or holography or dynamic material properties.

Usually only one focused and perfectly aligned source is used, but multiple wavelength sources could be used with different amounts of phase shift if the dielectric constant is known at each wavelength.

The optical result is shown by the contrast of modulated wavelengths mixed against the unmodulated wavelengths with a high resolution interference pattern.  The path lengths of each split optical beam are critically balanced for equal time delay. This requires precision leadscrews and granite slab table.

The voltage controlled dielectric may be considered as the static fine tuning for maximum transmission of light after mixing or the difference phase and frequency of the dynamic modulation of concern.

Comment: Is what I posted in the link under the word "Comsol" not a mach zehnder modulator, then?

Comment: It is.  ... a simple model for optical wavelet modulation analysis. Instead of adjust balance for demodulation, it is modulating for effects. https://www.comsol.com/model/download/344271/models.woptics.mach_zehnder_modulator.pdf

Comment: Could you clarify what you mean.  I don't understand

Comment: Any passive modulator can be used to modulate CW or demodulate modulated wavelets with coherent reference

Comment: This is the same as a phase "mixer". In this case electro-optical.

Comment: So can I mix an optical signal composed of more than one frequency with a constant phase?